# jQuery ajax call with REST API in sequence

Tags: jquery, ajax, multithreading, rest

I would like to ask a little help for you. My problem a quite difficult, but I hope you can help me :)
I have an REST API collection. The URL1 provide a list of names. The URL2 contains a property of the URL1's name. (for example URL2?name=URL1.name).

URL1 -> Adam, Juliet, George

URL2?name=Adam ->ID, Property1 etc.
(the results are in JSON)

I made this code for the solution:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var $data_v = $('#content');

    var name = []; //store the name list

    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "URL1",
        success: function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i, data){
              name[i] = data;
              console.log("Array: "+name[i]);
            });
        }
    }).done(function(){
            console.log("Succesful Array upload. The array size: "+name.length);
            for (var item_i=0; item_i<10; item_i++) { //name.length

                (function(item_i) { // protects i in an immediately called function 
                     $.getJSON( "URL2/?"+name[item_i]+"&any_other_property", function( data_items ) {
                       var items = [];
                       console.log("ID"+data_items[0]);
                       console.log("Property 1"+data_items[1]);
                    });

                })(item_i);                 
            }           
    });

console.log("Outside The array size: "+name.length);

});
```

Problem 1: The REST server has a request maximum, so if I run this code It do not display all property, because It stops and I got 503 error. I tried the setTimeout and .delay(), but if I ran this code It did not care with them.

Problem 2: I tried call the first 10's property, but the return values were not in order (for example the IDs: 1,0,4,6,2,3...).

All points are important for me, because I would like to upload this datas to the database.

Do you have any idea or experience, how can I solve this problems? 
I would be very grateful for any ideas.
Thanks in advance.

PS: Sorry for the URL, but I can not publish it.

Comment: is it your rest server?do you have access to the code that generates the rest api?

Comment: yes it is a test server. No I just can access for the JSON, if I see/use the link. So this link (URL1, URL2) you can see in the browser shows the json model.

Comment: check the api documentation if it has the option of joining multiple tabel in a api call , another solution will be to do the api calls only once and save the data to a personal db where you will do a join query

Comment: Unfortunetly, do not have opportunity to join tables.

Comment: Do you know any opportunity to I slow the requests or do the request in sequence? For example From the array it sees what is the name, the secound request shows the propertys and wait the return vale. If it is done start the next.

Comment: you can try promises

Comment: I have not heard this command yet, but I try it. I seems a good idea.

Comment: Do you have any idea how should I rebulid this code?

Comment: a simple idea will be to do a recursive function instead of a loop

Answer (score 0):

try this recursive function:

```
var item_i = 0;
function recursiv(item_i) {
 $.getJSON( "URL2/?"+name[item_i]+"&any_other_property", function( data_items ) {
                       var items = [];
                       console.log("ID"+data_items[0]);
                       console.log("Property 1"+data_items[1]);
                       item_i++;
                       if(item_i <10) {
                            recursiv(item_i);
                       }

                    });
};
```

Comment: It is a good idea i will try it, but my main problem is the fast requests.
Do you think have any opportunity to I slow the requests. For example 1 request every sec?

Comment: i hope you used `setTimeout` function ,why do you need a timeout in the first place ??

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the ideas and helps.
My solution was this little code:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});
```

The requests are really slow, but it is not give 503 error.